# How to detect beacon battery percentage in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I am using Estimote SDK 4.14.0. It provides the battery percentage only when i connect with them.i need to know, On which version it supports to detect battery percentage without connecting.

How to detect beacon battery percentage without connecting?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can get the beacon battery status directly from the web or you can store battery status whenever beacon disconnects at last.

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to get this info without connecting.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the state of your beacons' battery in the Kontakt.io Web Panel.

Simply log into your account, got to Infrastructure>Beacons, select the beacon you would like to review, and on the Device information section under the General tab, you'll see the battery level displayed along the last connection date. Because beacons can't connect to our API directly, both of these represent the last time our API was reported this battery level.

Comment: there is no other way to check battery level

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using Estimote Beacons.